# Factory relationship returning null laravel testing

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to unit testing a service that handles the registration of a user in Laravel.

This is the service:

```
public function completeRegistration(Collection $data)
    {
        $code = $data->get('code');
        $registerToken = $this->fetchRegisterToken($code);

        DB::beginTransaction();

        $registerToken->update(['used_at' => Carbon::now()]);
        $user = $this->userRepository->update($data, $registerToken->user);
        $token = $user->createToken(self::DEFAULT_TOKEN_NAME);

        DB::commit();

        return [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token->plainTextToken,
        ];
    }
```

Where the `update` method has the following signature:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\User;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

interface UserRepositoryInterface
{
    public function create(Collection $data): User;
    public function update(Collection $data, User $user): User;
}
```

With my test being:

```
/**
     * Test a user can register
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_user_can_complete_registration()
    {
        $userRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock(UserRepositoryInterface::class);
        $registerTokenRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock(RegisterTokenRepository::class);
        $userFactory = User::factory()->make();
        $registerTokenFactory = RegisterToken::factory()
            ->for($userFactory)
            ->timestamped()
            ->make(['user_id' => $userFactory->id]);

        dd($registerTokenFactory->user);

        $userRepositoryMock
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->once()
            ->andReturn($userFactory);

        ....

    }
```

When I run `phpunit --filter=test_user_can_complete_registration` I get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Unit\Services\Auth\AuthServiceTest::test_user_can_complete_registration
TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Mockery_0_App_Repositories_User_UserRepositoryInterface::update() must be an instance of App\Models\User, null given, called in /var/www/app/Services/Auth/AuthService.php on line 64

/var/www/app/Services/Auth/AuthService.php:64
/var/www/tests/Unit/Services/Auth/AuthServiceTest.php:88
```

This tells me that the `user` relationship on `$registerTokenFactory` is null. When I do:

```
public function test_user_can_complete_registration()
{
   ...
   dd($registerTokenFactory->user);
}
```

I get the output `null`. I'm trying to test the service without hitting the database. How can I attach the `user` relationship to the `$registerTokenFactory` object? I have tried using `for` and trying to attach directly:

```
$registerTokenFactory = RegisterToken::factory()
            ->for($userFactory)
            ->timestamped()
            ->make(['user_id' => $userFactory->id, 'user' => $userFactory]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Laravel` factories `make()` does only create the model and does not save it. For relationship to work, you will need your models to be saved.

```
   $userFactory = User::factory()->create();
```

Since you do not want to use a Database, which is wrong in my opinion. People don't like writing tests, so when we have to do it make it simple, mocking everything to avoid databases is a pain. Instead an alternative is to you `Sqlite` to run in memory, fast and easy. A drawback is some functionality does not work there JSON fields and the version that are in most Ubuntu distributions does not respect foreign keys.

If you want to follow the path you are already on, assigned the user on the object would work, you have some left out bits of the code i assume.

```
$userRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock(UserRepositoryInterface::class);
$registerTokenRepositoryMock = Mockery::mock(RegisterTokenRepository::class);

$user = User::factory()->make();

$registerToken = RegisterToken::factory()
    ->for($userFactory)
    ->timestamped()
    ->make(['user_id' => $user->id]);

$registerToken->user = $user;

$registerTokenRepositoryMock
    ->expects('fetchRegisterToken')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn($registerToken);

$userRepositoryMock
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->once()
    ->andReturn($user);

// execute the call
```